# Whether to go for TestNG or Junit for UI Automation?

Tags: selenium, junit, testng

Planning to build a automation framework using selenium with java.

Quite confused to execute the testcase, whether to go with testng or junit.

Please provide your suggestions...

Comment: Both work, pick the one you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having lot of dependencies and input constrains you can opt for TestNg. It is having many annotations which controls your test suite in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/). It compares JUnit 4 and TestNG.

I personally use TestNG as it provides more annotations and dependencies. Everything is explained in an article above.

Hope it helps!